# How to convert a dataframe with MultiIndex indices and columns that has string values to a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` which looks as follows:

```
module  wind_on_share   wind_off_share  wind_total_share
variable    Wind-onshore power generation   Wind-offshore power generation  Wind power generation
model   scenario            
AIM/CGE 2.0 ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C  high    NaN medium
SSP1-19 NaN NaN high
GCAM 4.2    SSP1-19 NaN NaN medium
IMAGE 3.0.1 SSP1-19 NaN NaN low
SSP1-26 NaN NaN low
```

The dataframe has MultiIndex indices containing `model` and `scenario`. Similarly, it has MultiIndex columns containing `module` and `variable` which looks like follow:

```
[(   'wind_on_share',  'Wind-onshore power generation'),
            (  'wind_off_share', 'Wind-offshore power generation'),
            ('wind_total_share',          'Wind power generation')]
```

I'd like to convert this dataframe into a pivot table such that the `module` or `variable` in the existing columns are added to the indices. And the values should be shown in a single column as `values`. It should looks something as in the screenshot of Excel below: [image]

I have tried different things with `df1.pivot_table(index = "", values = "")` But it has not worked out so far. And I am not sure which parameters should I pass to index and values. I also tried `df1.unstack()`and `df1.reset_index()`, but I am not again sure which parameters to pass as it has not worked out so far. What would be the appropriate way to create a pivot table in this case?

The data frame looks like following in dictionary format.

```
{('wind_on_share',
  'Wind-onshore power generation'): {('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): 'high', ('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'SSP1-19'): nan, ('GCAM 4.2', 'SSP1-19'): nan, ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'SSP1-19'): nan, ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'SSP1-26'): nan, ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): 'low', ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0',
   'SSP1-19'): nan, },
 ('wind_off_share',
  'Wind-offshore power generation'): {('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): nan, ('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'SSP1-19'): nan, ('GCAM 4.2', 'SSP1-19'): nan, ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'SSP1-19'): nan, ('IMAGE 3.0.1', 'SSP1-26'): nan, ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): 'low', ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0',
   'SSP1-19'): nan},
 ('wind_total_share',
  'Wind power generation'): {('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): 'medium', ('AIM/CGE 2.0',
   'SSP1-19'): 'high', ('GCAM 4.2', 'SSP1-19'): 'medium', ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'SSP1-19'): 'low', ('IMAGE 3.0.1',
   'SSP1-26'): 'low', ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0', 'ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C'): 'medium', ('MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0',
   'SSP1-19'): 'low'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop level `-1` from column (since you don't want it in the resulting dataframe), then stack the dataframe with `dropna=False` to keep the `NaN` values for the indices, then finally call `to_frame` passing the column name as `value` to convert the stacked series to a dataframe.

```py
>>> df.droplevel(-1,1).stack(dropna=False).to_frame('value')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                                                              value
AIM/CGE 2.0         ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C wind_on_share       high
                                           wind_off_share       NaN
                                           wind_total_share  medium
                    SSP1-19                wind_on_share        NaN
                                           wind_off_share       NaN
                                           wind_total_share    high
GCAM 4.2            SSP1-19                wind_on_share        NaN
                                           wind_off_share       NaN
                                           wind_total_share  medium
IMAGE 3.0.1         SSP1-19                wind_on_share        NaN
                                           wind_off_share       NaN
                                           wind_total_share     low
                    SSP1-26                wind_on_share        NaN
                                           wind_off_share       NaN
                                           wind_total_share     low
MESSAGE-GLOBIOM 1.0 ADVANCE_2030_Price1.5C wind_on_share        low
                                           wind_off_share       low
                                           wind_total_share  medium
                    SSP1-19                wind_on_share        NaN
                                           wind_off_share       NaN
                                           wind_total_share     low
```